# Primefaces Print Dynamic Images

Tags: image, dynamic, printing, primefaces

I tried to load an image dynamically, and everything works.
The image I is loaded and displayed correctly in a dynamic,
I added the tag for printing.
Now if I ask to print the image created dynamically I can not print.

```
       <pou:commandButton value="Print" type="button" icon="ui-icon-print">  
                    <pou:printer target="image"  />  
       </pou:commandButton>     
       <pou:graphicImage id="image" value="#{printDynamicBean.graphicIMG}" />
```

My bean does like this:

```
    public StreamedContent getGraphicIMG() {
        //Graphic   
        BufferedImage bufferedImg;
        try {
            bufferedImg = ImageIO.read(baseImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        try {

          Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImg.createGraphics();
          g2.setColor(Color.black);
          int style = Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC;
          Font f1 = new Font("TimesNewRoman", style , 60);
          g2.setFont(f1);
          g2.drawString("Hello Print", 80, 580);
          ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ImageIO.write(bufferedImg, "png", os);
          graphicIMG = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()), "image/png");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(PrintCartelliniBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return graphicIMG;


}
```

it is as if she had forgotten the image created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
using CDI bean you can do this : 

@Model
public class ImageBean {

    private StreamedContent image;

    @Produces
    @Named
    public StreamedContent getImage() {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderResponse()) {
            // rendering the view, return a stub StreamedContent to generate right URL.
            image = new DefaultStreamedContent();
        } else {
            // requesting the image
            image = your dynamic image;
        }

        return image;
    }
}
```

- in your view : `<pou:graphicImage id="image" value="#{image}" />`