# Primefaces Printing Dynamic Streamed Contents

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF application which display dynamically generated images perfectly developed after going through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304967/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-streamedcontent-within-pdatatable) using primefaces. When I want to print a part of the web page which contain the images using p:printer, all the content of the selected segment is printed except the dynamically generated images.Images are represented by a very small icon.

I have tried the suggestions in the following links, but failed.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861025/primefaces-print-dynamic-images)
[2](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=28347)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434517/pgraphicimage-not-rendering-image)

It is essential for the app to print dynamic image, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used css to hide all other divs during print time and used window.print command.

Print button

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="noPrintBlock"  ajax="false" value="Print" onclick="window.print();" actionListener="#{patientReportController.markAsPrinted()}" />
```

The component which I want to print.

```
<p:panel styleClass="printBlock" id="divPrint" >
</p:panel>
```

Example of a component which I do not want to print

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="noPrintBlock">
</h:panelGroup>
```

CSS

```
@media print{
    .noPrintBlock{
        display: none;
    }
    .printBlock{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

}
```